# Fusion: No matching native image found

Tags: c#, fusion

I have installed a Windows service via a new MSI build. But the service just finishes going through the constructor before stopping without explanation. I get the following in the fusion log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2013-07-17 @ 12:48:29) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\SoW\Market Communicator\Company.Market.Communicator.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = SoW\kasper
LOG: DisplayName = Company.Market.Administration, Version=1.3.0.49, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/SoW/Market Communicator/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : Company.Market.Communicator, Version=1.3.0.140, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: Start binding of native image Company.Market.Administration, Version=1.3.0.49, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
WRN: No matching native image found.
```

But I have looked into the installed dll and it is what it should be looking for. I don't understand why "the opereation failed".

```
C:\Program Files\SoW\Market Communicator>asminfo Company.Market.Administration.dll
```

result:

```
Company.Market.Administration, Version=1.3.0.49, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken =null | Amd64
```

It looks like that it is the file it is looking for. But why does it fail then?